# Explain head and tail methods in NodeVisitor interface in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

While Jsoup appears to be very good library to scrap HTML but unfortunately its API has virtually no documentation. Here is the API for Nodevisitor class:

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/NodeVisitor.html

Can you explain what head and tail means (these terms usually associated with queues) and what datastructures and algorithms are being implied here and why I would implement head or tail?

Comment: did u find out any answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

In a "general" context, `head` refers to the first element of a list, and `tail` to the remainder of the list. This is especially popular in functional programming where it is used to traverse lists recursively instead of iteratively.

However, in this specific context, I don't know ...however, I'm always suspicious about the quality of undocumented APIs.